# Problem with empty array being returned when referencing mongoose schemas

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, backend

I am trying to solve the promblem where const userPosts = await Post.find({user : req.user.id }) will only returns an empty array in the following code.

```
getPost : async (req, res) => {
      try {
        const userPosts = await Post.find({user : req.user.id})
        res.render('profile.ejs',{posts : userPosts, user : req.user})
        // console.log(req.user.id)
        console.log(userPosts)
      }catch(err){
        console.error(err)
      }
    },
```

I am using a post schema which is taking a ref to my other schema User like so ie

const PostSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
title : {
type: String,
required : true,
},
caption : {
type: String,
required : true,
},
user: {
type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
ref: 'User',
},
})

const UserSchema = new mongoose.Schema( {
username : {
type : String,
unique : true,
},
email : {
type : String,
unique : true,
},
password : {
type : String,
}
})

The ultimate goal is to query the Post collection of all posts created by the logged in user, when logging req.user.id i get the correct id that is present in the User database, but there seems to be a disconnect with the referencing. I would greatly appreciate any help, thankyou.

The ultimate goal is to query the Post collection of all posts created by the logged in user, when logging req.user.id i get the correct id that is present in the User database, but there seems to be a disconnect with the referencing where only an emoty array is returned when i know there are documents created that match the user id. I would greatly appreciate any help, thankyou.

Answer (score 0):

req.query.id is a string,to fix it you can use

```
await Post.find({user : new mongoose.Types.ObjectId(req.user.id)}),
```

ObjectId as String is supported by findById, where Id should be primary key.